# How to customize the error page for REST API Failures in Azure AD B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Customizing the error page for REST API Failures which we are calling in the Orchestration Steps :

We have a scenario where we need to call the Rest API before any Self asserted Page being presented to the user

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Rest-API-Call" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Some-Rest API " />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Some-Rest API">
    <DisplayName>REST  call</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, 
    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl"> https://{url}</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
        <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">token</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
        <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Unable to Process your Request</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="token" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Whenever this API Fails with status code 4xx and 5xx, we will be getting the default error message which Microsoft is providing

`Sorry, We are having trouble signing you in. We track these errors automatically , but if the problem persists  feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again...`

We are getting this Page, Could you please help us is there any way we can customize this error Page, with some default exception html Page
where we can show our customized page instead of this default page.

Answer (score 0):

The default API error page is defined in the content definition api.error if you started from one of the custom policy starter packs. You can modify that content definition to point to your own HTML page so you can customize the styling. Here's a link to that doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

api.error however only displays on unhandled exceptions which might not cover your use case.

An answer to another post ([Error handling in Azure B2C Custom Policy REST Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856223/error-handling-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy-rest-call)) from someone on the engineering team states that anything but a 200 from an API halts the journey execution and returns an error to the app immediately, so unless you put the rest call in a validation tech profile, this is the behavior you're going to get.

Comment: We have tried to customize the error page with Our own page and Modified the Content Definition for it.
`<ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
 <LoadUri>https://ourblobstorage/error-locked.html</LoadUri>
 <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.1.0</DataUri>
 <Metadata>
  <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
 </Metadata>
 </ContentDefinition>`

And we have added this api.error

Comment: `<TechnicalProfile Id="Some-Rest API">
    <DisplayName>REST  call</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, 
    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl"> https://{url}</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
        <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">token</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>`

Comment: `<Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.error</Item>
        <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Unable to Process your Request</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="token" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>`
Now, we are getting below Error message instead of the error page which is defined in the loaduri of api.error

Comment: `Error: server_error
AADB2C90075: Unable to Process your Request
Correlation ID: 20ed7635-3ee8-49db-81b2-2ec034ac791d
Timestamp: 2022-07-12 10:39:20Z`

We are not getting the loaduri page which is defined for api.error, Are we missing something...

Could you please help us.

Comment: The metadata item ContentDefinitionReferenceId will not work as you are expecting for a restful technical profile. Here are the valid metadata items for the restful provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata

Comment: I've edited my answer after getting more information.