# When REST-API in Orchestration step returns error, display error page

Tags: error-handling, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We're calling a REST-API technical profile in the `OrchestrationStep`. In the event where the REST-API returns an error, it redirects back to the application and displays the error as a query string.
(e.g.`#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a+No+code+provided%3a+Conflict+error%3b+RequestId%3a+No+request+id+provided.%3b+Additional+Info%3a+No+additional+info+provided.%...)`

Is there a way that instead of displaying the error in the query string, it will display a custom error page?

Also why is `api.error` not displayed in this case?

Note: The REST-API is needed to be called in the `OrchestrationStep` rather than the `ValidationTechnicalProfile`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oauth/OpenId, the way B2C responds to the application is based on the response_mode query parameter that's passed to it when you call the policy. The response_mode can be query, form_post, or fragment.

Here's a link to the Microsoft's auth code flow docs that shows the response_mode query parameter in action along with it's available options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#1-get-an-authorization-code

api.error only displays for unhandled exceptions and doesn't cover every use case.

An answer to another post ([Error handling in Azure B2C Custom Policy REST Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856223/error-handling-in-azure-b2c-custom-policy-rest-call)) from someone on the engineering team states that anything but a 200 from an API halts the journey execution and returns an error to the app immediately, so unless you put the rest call in a validation tech profile, this is the behavior you're going to get.

Comment: If we change the 'response_mode' to 'form_post' or 'fragment', will the error be displayed in the 'api.error' page instead?

Comment: It will not. I've edited my answer after more information.